# Insert string/source command after #!/bin/bash line in a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to insert a certain string after the #!/bin/bash line in a separate bash file but I'm running into issues with my sed statement not parsing through the characters correctly. I'm basing my example off of solutions here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/how-to-insert-text-after-a-certain-string-in-a-file

So for example, I have a sed statement that is trying to write a source command to scriptOne.sh:

```
sed '/#!/bin/bash/a source /root/documents/folder/scriptTwo.sh' /root/home/scriptOne.sh
```

I would like scriptOne.sh to go from this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to this after running my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /root/documents/folder/scriptTwo.sh
```

The sed command doesn't seem to work I think because of the extra slashes and characters it's having trouble separating from an actual string vs regex characters. Ideally I would also like to insert an extra blank line between the #!/bin/bash and source command, but my main goal is just to insert that source command under the #!/bin/bash.

Update:

I tried this in my script (just another random script located in /home/student/Desktop):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '\~#!/bin/bash~ a\
\
source /root/documents/folder/scriptTwo.sh' /root/home/scriptOne.sh
```

but when I run it, scriptOne.sh does not get altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `sed` like this:

```bash
sed -i.bak '\~#!/bin/bash~ a\
\
source /root/documents/folder/scriptTwo.sh' /root/home/scriptOne.sh
```

Comment: Hello, my script looks like this: 

#!/bin/bash

sed '\~#!/bin/bash~ a\
\
source /root/documents/folder/scriptTwo.sh' /root/home/scriptOne.sh

And when I run the script, scriptOne.sh doesn't seem to change - it only has the bin/bash line with no source command being added after that.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, I described my problem in my updated post

Comment: Check my updated answer. You just needed `-i` flag